# Moving a single Windows 2008 box to a clustered implementation?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, cluster, failover, windows-cluster

I have a system that currently runs on a single box, Windows 2008 Enterprise.  This is just used as a web server.

What is involved in creating a cluster?  Basically doing this for availability reasons - the load on the system will be pretty light.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article on [IIS and Failover Clustering in 2008](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/27/iis7-and-failover-clustering.aspx)

Comment: That article works. We're using it for static web-serving, and it works great.